# Rails: has_many, but also has_one by a different name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say a `User` has many `Document`s, and a single `Document` they're currently working on. How do I represent this in rails?

I want to say `current_user.current_document = Document.first` (with or without current_ in front of document) and have it not change the `current_user.documents` collection.

This is what I have:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
  has_one :document
end
```

the problem is that when I say `current_user.document = some_document`, it removes the document previously stored in `current_user.document` from `current_user.documents`. This makes sense due to the `has_one` relationship that `Document` has, but isn't what I want. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your Models to

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents

  # you could also use :document, but I would recommend this:
  belongs_to :current_document, :class_name => "Document"
end
```

P.S. But beware of cyclic saves. If you create a new User (and don't save it yet) and set `current_document` and then save the User you might get stack overflows or other crazy errors.

Comment: Thanks! And just to be clear for others, the column name in this case will be `current_document_id` in the `users` table.