# Rails has_many / has_one same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

So, I have two models, Collection and Folder.

Within each Collection there is one root folder. Folders all belong to a Collection, but can also be nested within each other.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199049/rails-has-many-but-also-has-one-by-a-different-name), I wrote my models like shown below. I also added a callback, because I always want a Collection to start out with a root folder.

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :master_collection, :class_name => 'Collection', :foreign_key => :root_folder_id
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Folder'
  has_many :subfolders, :class_name => 'Folder', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  ...
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :root_folder, :class_name => 'Folder'
  has_many :folders

  after_create :setup_root_folder

  private
  def setup_root_folder
    self.root_folder = Folder.create(:name => 'Collection Root', :collection => self )
  end
end
```

In Folders I have the columns: parent_id, folder_id
In Collections I have the column: root_folder_id

This seems like it should work, but I get this strange behavior in the console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > c = Collection.create(:name=>"Example")
 => #<Collection id: 6, name: "Example", ...timestamps..., root_folder_id: 8> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :003 > f = c.root_folder
 => #<Folder id: 8, parent_id: nil, name: "Collection Root", ...timestamps..., collection_id: 6> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > f.master_collection
 => nil
```

So, clearly the association works on the collection side, but the root folder is not able to find the collection it is the root of, even though the foreign key is available and ActiveRecord isn't raising any errors on using the association...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `root_folder_id` is set by the `setup_root_folder` method? I'd expect to see a `save` to update the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this is what's happening:

1. You create Collection C
2. C is saved to the database
3. Rails calls `C.after_create`
4. You create Folder F
5. F is saved to the database
6. C's `root_folder_id` is set to F's `id`
7. *This change is NOT saved to the database*
8. You call `F.master_collection`
9. F queries the database, looking for Collections with `coleections.root_folder_id = folders.id`
10. Since C's new `root_folder_id` hasn't been saved, F doesn't find anything

If you want to test this, call `c.save` in your example code before you call `f.master_collection` - and you should get the collection, like you expect (you might need a `f.reload` too).

That said, I've never liked double `belongs_to`s (Folder belongs_to Collection + Collection belongs_to root_folder).  Instead, I'd recommend:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :root_folder, :class_name => 'Folder', :conditions => {:parent_id => nil}

    # ...other stuff...
end
```

Hope that helps!

**PS:**  Your definition of `Folder.master_collection` will only give you back a collection if you call it from a root folder - all other folders will just return nil, since no collections have `root_folder_id`s that point to them.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: RE: master_collection only works on Root Folder, that is what I intended. Still processing the rest of your answer, thanks!

Comment: @Andrew  All's well, then - just checking.  Cheers!

Comment: RE: `has_one :root_folder .... :conditions { :parent_id => nil }`. There can be more than one collection and each one has a root folder. How does ActiveRecord know which folder with nil parent_id belongs to which collection?

Comment: @Andrew - There's an implicit `:foreign_key => :collection_id` in that statement.  It's a Rails convention thing.  That same implicit foreign key lets you just call `has_many :folders` - Rails will assume that anything that belongs to Model `MyModel` will do it with `my_model_id` (unless you tell it otherwise).

Comment: OH! So- using the existing collection_id, where collection_id = X AND parent_id = nil == root_folder. Nice! Yes, I like that a lot more than the double belongs_to approach.